# trying to inegrate a spellchecker library in my application

Tags: java, javascript, eclipse, jsp

I am using eclipse IDE for web development....I hav e made my application and now i m trying to integrate a spellchecker in my application..and also as per the limitations of my project i have to use a spellchecker that uses jsp...so i surfed net and found a few and downloaded there demo version...now i m trying to integrate them in my library but its becoming difficult for me to do the same.one i have integrated but the other two are giving me a hard time....If any one could suggest to me nice tutorial which will give me good assist inintegrating a library into my application or can anyone take the trouble of giving me the minute details on how to do it......
the files contained in the spellchecker are of jsp js inc and obviously the jar file....

I would really appreciate any help.....

Comment: Did u look at http://sourceforge.net/projects/jspspellcheck/ ?

Comment: Actually this is one of the two which I have downloaded.....some of its jsp files are showing error....may be some refrencing has gone wrong which i am tring to fix but am not able to.....thats why i was looking for a tutorial...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have used **[Jazzy](http://sourceforge.net/projects/jazzy/)**  for web application. You have to these API in your jsp. You can also play with AJAX as well. If you application deployed in single environment and not stable then you have take care of dictionary where Jazzy put words. Because when you add words it will be stored in the file. That kind of difficulty you can face in if an application multiple server. Please find [tutorial](http://www.google.co.in/url?sa=t&source=web&cd=1&ved=0CBgQFjAA&url=http://ulyxemozyjumo.onsugar.com/Jazzy-Spell-Checker-Tutorial-11850671&rct=j&q=jsp%20spell%20checker%20using%20Jazzy%20tutorials&ei=ykDvTd3GAY_msQOf_dn_Bg&usg=AFQjCNE8878BvkIGNLwpDTjJLJX5A5IkXw&cad=rja).